# php problem with post parameter / simplexml

Tags: php, simplexml

i want to access a certain node of my xml with given id which i'm getting from a post parameter like this:

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$xml->content[$id];
```

unfortunately it doesn't work - returns empty. seems like because $id is problably of type string, not integer.
i tried to convert it like:

```
$id = int $id;
```

which gave me this error:

```
syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE
```

any ideas how to fix it?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use

```
$id = (int) $id;
```

instead of $id = int $id;

Answer (score 2):

Typecasting is performed with `(int)$str` or `intval($str)` in PHP:

```
$id = (int)$id;
```

Or

```
$id = intval($id);
```